# My employer want me to do 5 minutes tasks outside business hours

Tags: management, manager, work-time

My employer want me to do small task outside business hours. I don´t want to do those tasks for five minutes and only get paid for 5 minutes. What is a reasonable to do in this situation? 
The tasks are not that hard and needs to be done outside regular hours.

The task is to check an app that we are developing. It sometimes crash if the phone wake up and haven’t been used for about 4 hours. I need to check if it´s gone

Comment: Can you do them during work hours?  If there's any other information you can add to clear assumptions, please [edit] the question to add more details.

Comment: Is it a regular task? Or only once?

Comment: It will be regular for about 3 weeks

Comment: Surely as an app developer you are FLSA exempt? Or do you fall below the salary treshhold?

Comment: How are you being paid right now? Salary, by hour, or some other agreement?

Comment: I think you need to add a country tag to your question and specify if you are paid hourly or salary.

Comment: Check your handbook and time tracking system. Many will not allow you to enter in less than 1/2 hour increments. If that is the case, check with boss. Maybe you are to charge 1/2 hour for each 5 min. Sounds like a nice deal to me.

Comment: Do you need to go into the office, or can you do it from home? If the latter, I would personally just do it and leave the office 5 minutes early.

Comment: Can't you automate this somehow?

Comment: Assuming I was working on this app or even involved in it, I'd consider the occasional check part of my job and not necessarily even bill for it unless it took significant time to track something down.  If it wasn't my software, my employer demanded it and/or I had to do extra paperwork to show that I was checking on a schedule, that would be a different matter and I'd probably start treating the time spent as comp-time, leaving earlier the next day.  The comp time seems better to me than getting paid for 5 minutes for some reason...

Comment: If you just need to check the app after 4+ hours on no use, why can't it wait for the start of the next business day?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since your boss is willing to pay you, this would be standard paid overtime.

You should evaulate yourself if this overtime requires additional commutes or expenses, and try to come to an agreement to find an ideal compensation for external problems caused by this short additional work.

You should also check your employment contract and see if there are regulations about overtime (this may be job and country dependent).

As the work isn't much (5 minutes is really nothing) I would just do the work and be paid for it, unless it really messes up your day schedule. Refusing may bring a lot of negative reputation and consequences, while accepting might show that you're a reliable and committed employee.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere  It's implied in the question text: " I don´t want to do those tasks for five minutes and only get paid for 5 minutes. "

Comment: @JoeStrazzere actually, the whole answer is based on the assumption that he gets paid for his time. It would be very different if it was for free, and it surely wouldn't be a "sure, go for it!"

Answer (score 7):

You don't like working 5 minutes out-of-band because that's not 5 minutes, but also the time you need to reserve around it: you need to be available, have a connection and don't do anything else (like for example drink alcohol).

So let me challenge the frame of your question: *Why* is there an app that crashes after 4 hours? You don't need to observe this. You need to **fix** it. And why are you supposed to look every few hours for three weeks? You are not manual labor. **Automate** it.

In other words: if you are *developing* that app, then go and **develop that app**. Don't just stand by and let it fail under observation.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds that this task takes 5 minutes every day for three weeks, can easily be done at home, and someone has to do it. You can tell your boss that you are not doing it, and in that case he'll either get someone else to do it or does it himself.

I would say that you have an excellent chance here to either demonstrate with relative little effort that you are someone who can be counted on, and the boss will owe you, or to demonstrate that you cannot be relied on at all. What you do can make a huge difference to your standing with the company. Whatever you do will not have immediate consequences, but it will be remembered.

(All assuming I understood this right. Every evening, you put your works phone to sleep, take it home, and 4 1/2 hours later you wake it up to check whether it crashes, so it's a minimum of actual work involved).

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like your employer is asking you to be *on call*. They're asking you to be available to fix a problem that happens at off-work times unexpectedly.

If you're going to be on call, I would suggest first checking your local labor laws regarding on-call employees; some require you to be compensated even if you aren't asked to fix anything.

Second, I would make sure that you had a very specific agreement with your employer:

1. What is the hours covered?  Is your employer expecting you to wake up at 2am, or is it only 6am-10pm or such?
2. How quickly are you expected to log in?  How many hours do you have to respond?
3. What is the protocol for handling situations when you are unavailable for more than the expected response time (either due to paid-time-off/vacation, sickness, or going to see a movie on a Saturday)?
4. How often do you need to check in (if any), or is it a push notification system (either actually push notification, or you get a text/email/call)?
5. How much are you being compensated for this?

I would ask for compensation for the on-call nature of the job *above and beyond* the 5-minute compensation.  In other words, it's an inconvenience for you to be available at non-work hours, and if the expectation is for you to have that availability for a certain period, you should be paid even if you don't do any work - you are being available, meaning you might have to choose different activities than you'd prefer.

Of course, the compensation level depends on the annoyance factor: if you have six hours to respond or something, and only 8am-8pm Mon-Sat, then it's much less of a pain than if you have 1 hour to respond and it's 24/7.  Then, you don't bill for the 5 minute calls - though you should have a number of expected calls written into the agreement, and if it goes significantly above that then you should renegotiate.

Something like:

I will be available for calls from 8am-10pm Mon-Sat.

- I will respond to text messages within 2 hours confirming I have it by texting , and will handle the situation within 4 hours and confirm it is handled via texting .
- If I am on approved paid time off, my backup or supervisor will handle this responsibility for the duration of my paid time off.  If I am not on paid time off but will be unavailable for a period of time, I will notify  at least one hour prior to that period of unavailability and include the duration of unavailability.
- I will respond only to text notifications of the issue; I will not proactively check on the application during this time.
- In compensation for this, my salary will increase by  / I will be paid a bonus of  (the latter if it is not a permanent part of the job).